# PostgreSQL - type of a numeric literal like 1.0 or 100.0?

Tags: sql, postgresql

If in a PostgreSQL function, I use values like 1.0 or 100.0 what type is this literal assumed to have?

I mean, if I use these literals in some expression, I want to know what implicit type conversions/promotions take place? To know this I need to know the type of 1.0 or 100.0?

E.g. if I type

`CAST ( ( 1.0 * A ) / B AS NUMERIC(12,6) );`

where `A` and `B` are integers what type promotions take place here (before the explicit cast to `NUMERIC(12,6)` ?!

I have hard time finding information about this in the official PostgreSQL docs.

Answer (score 3):

This is explained in the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS):

> A numeric constant that contains neither a decimal point nor an exponent is initially presumed to be type integer if its value fits in type integer (32 bits); otherwise it is presumed to be type bigint if its value fits in type bigint (64 bits); otherwise it is taken to be type numeric. Constants that contain decimal points and/or exponents are always initially presumed to be type numeric.

As for your expression, it is evaluated first and then converted to the stated type.

Comment: Thanks. So it's numeric, not float? And numeric is with what precision and scale?

Comment: "numeric, not float?" No not float the manual says type **numeric**  " And with what precision and scale?"  @peter.petrov  i assume the precision and scale is automatic the manual shows some example which are valid each number is different in precision and scale.. Also the documentation is mentioning more "you can force a numeric value to be treated as type real (**float4**) by writing:REAL '1.23' -- string style 1.23::REAL -- PostgreSQL (historical) style"

Comment: It's `numeric` without precision and scale (no limit). See the documentation on `numeric`.